# import SQL server database to HDFS or to HIVE

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

I deployed a hdinsight cluster on azure. i need to copy SQL database to Hdfs Location or directly to hive. I am New to establishing these connections. Please let me know the suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: You can probably check this link to help you out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749882.aspx. It should work on some cases the other way around to transfer data from SQL Server to HDInsight. You would to use hive though to create the place where to load the data too.

Comment: SSMS 2014 @asemprini87

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are not clear on requirement what exactly you need. Can you provide more details about this task?

But mean time I suggest you to verify configuration files(.xml) and connections for Hive or HDFS.

Below link might be helpful to you for debug :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-hive

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749882.aspx#sec3

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your requirement correctly,then you need to use Sqoop to import the SQL db into HDFS. Use Below command(if Sqoop is already installed).This command will copy the all tables in the schema to default location

```
 sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/<schema name> \
--username <username>
--pass<password>
```

Then you can use below command to check the tables that has been imported

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

For more info,you can visit https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/13132/best-practice-to-import-data-from-sql-server-to-hi.html